# Code for an Email that is sent with php code - task-> Sensitivity Label in Outook

Tags: php, email, outlook, joomla

I need some help.

I have a php code for a website. The website can send confirmation about data entry to specific email addresses. Is there any way that the email would be automatically labeled in Outlook with a Sensitivity Label?

would such a code work?
Would $sensitivityLabel work?

thank you for your help.

```
<?php

// some short cuts
$d = $this->data;

// Set the sensitivity label (replace 'Confidential' with the appropriate label name used in Outlook)
$sensitivityLabel = 'Confidential';

// Function to add a header to the email
function addHeader($name, $value) {
    header("$name: $value");
}

?>
<html>
<?php

// include any other necessary email headers
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/mail_headers.php';

// Add the sensitivity label header to the email
addHeader('Sensitivity', $sensitivityLabel);

$onSiteRequests = $this->model->getOnSiteRequestIndices();
$homeOfficeRequests = $this->model->getHomeOfficeRequestIndices();
?>
<body>

<!-- Email content goes here -->

</body>
</html>
```

I think this is the code for mailing.
Please click on the link to open the picture:
[sensitivity label in outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMGl2.png)

So the task is, that the company already defined sensitivity labels, and we need a sensitivity label for this particular email. Currently it shows "not set" Could you tell me how should I code it?

Thanks for your help :)

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_mailto
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_mailto
 */
class MailtoController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    /**
     * Show the form so that the user can send the link to someone
     *
     * @access public
     * @since 1.5
     */
    function mailto()
    {
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('com_mailto.formtime', time());
        JRequest::setVar('view', 'mailto');
        $this->display();
    }

    /**
     * Send the message and display a notice
     *
     * @access public
     * @since 1.5
     */
    function send()
    {
        // Check for request forgeries
        JSession::checkToken() or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

        $app    = JFactory::getApplication();
        $session = JFactory::getSession();
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $timeout = $session->get('com_mailto.formtime', 0);
        if ($timeout == 0 || time() - $timeout < 20) {
            JError::raiseNotice(500, JText:: _ ('COM_MAILTO_EMAIL_NOT_SENT'));
            return $this->mailto();
        }

        $SiteName   = $app->getCfg('sitename');
        $MailFrom   = $app->getCfg('mailfrom');
        $FromName   = $app->getCfg('fromname');

        $link       = MailtoHelper::validateHash(JRequest::getCMD('link', '', 'post'));

        // Verify that this is a local link
        if (!$link || !JURI::isInternal($link)) {
            //Non-local url...
            JError::raiseNotice(500, JText:: _ ('COM_MAILTO_EMAIL_NOT_SENT'));
            return $this->mailto();
        }

        // An array of email headers we do not want to allow as input
        $headers = array (  'Content-Type:',
                            'MIME-Version:',
                            'Content-Transfer-Encoding:',
                            'bcc:',
                            'cc:');

        // An array of the input fields to scan for injected headers
        $fields = array(
            'mailto',
            'sender',
            'from',
            'subject',
        );

        /*
         * Here is the meat and potatoes of the header injection test.  We
         * iterate over the array of form input and check for header strings.
         * If we find one, send an unauthorized header and die.
         */
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            foreach ($headers as $header)
            {
                if (strpos($_POST[$field], $header) !== false)
                {
                    JError::raiseError(403, '');
                }
            }
        }

        /*
         * Free up memory
         */
        unset ($headers, $fields);

        $email              = JRequest::getString('mailto', '', 'post');
        $sender             = JRequest::getString('sender', '', 'post');
        $from               = JRequest::getString('from', '', 'post');
        $subject_default    = JText::sprintf('COM_MAILTO_SENT_BY', $sender);
        $subject            = JRequest::getString('subject', $subject_default, 'post');

        // Check for a valid to address
        $error  = false;
        if (! $email  || ! JMailHelper::isEmailAddress($email))
        {
            $error  = JText::sprintf('COM_MAILTO_EMAIL_INVALID', $email);
            JError::raiseWarning(0, $error);
        }

        // Check for a valid from address
        if (! $from || ! JMailHelper::isEmailAddress($from))
        {
            $error  = JText::sprintf('COM_MAILTO_EMAIL_INVALID', $from);
            JError::raiseWarning(0, $error);
        }

        if ($error)
        {
            return $this->mailto();
        }

        // Build the message to send
        $msg    = JText :: _('COM_MAILTO_EMAIL_MSG');
        $body   = sprintf($msg, $SiteName, $sender, $from, $link);

        // Clean the email data
        $subject = JMailHelper::cleanSubject($subject);
        $body    = JMailHelper::cleanBody($body);
        $sender  = JMailHelper::cleanAddress($sender);

        // Send the email
        if (JFactory::getMailer()->sendMail($from, $sender, $email, $subject, $body) !== true)
        {
            JError::raiseNotice(500, JText:: _ ('COM_MAILTO_EMAIL_NOT_SENT'));
            return $this->mailto();
        }

        JRequest::setVar('view', 'sent');
        $this->display();
    }
}
```

Comment: `header` sends a HTTP response header back to the browser which initiated this PHP script. That has absolutely nothing to do with sending an email

Comment: I understand that you want to set the "Sensitivity" email header. Such an header is similar to "To", "From" and "Subject" so you can add it as an additional header in [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), if that's what you're using.

Comment: TIP: When asking a question about emailing with PHP it helps people to answer your question when they know how you send the email. Do you use the standard `mail()` function? PHPMailer? Just show the code. We love code here.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I uploaded another code. I think this is in charge of mailing. We use Joomla packages. I´m still new in coding so any suggestion can help a lot. thank you :)

Comment: I add the Joomla tag to your question, since that's what you're using for sending email. I found a [Joomla stack exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) that might be better suited for your question. Looking a [this answer there](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/18766/adding-smtp-header-to-message-sent-with-jmail) it seems you can send custom headers with a `JFactory::getMailer()` object, but you cannot use the `sendMail()` method.

Comment: thank you @KIKOSoftware I added a question on joomla stack exchange too